# Show that a set is a manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $n \ge 3 $.

How can I show that

$M:= \{(x_1,...,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{(0,...,0)\} | x_1^2+...+x_n^2 = x_1 \cdot...\cdot x_n \}$

is a manifold of class $C^1$?

Can anyone please tell me how can I imagine this set, or what is the standard way to do an exercise like this one?

Exam in 2 days. ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following theorem

### Theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and 
$$M_f=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:f(x)=0\}$$
If $(\nabla f)(p)\ne0$ for all $p\in M_f $ then $M_f$ is a differentiable manifold.

Comment: What does it mean, that $(\nabla f)(p)\ne0$?

Comment: $(\nabla f)(p)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})(p)$

Comment: So if $(x_1,...,x_n) \in M $ then $ \forall i \in \{ 1,2,...,n \} x_i \neq 0$  
and   
 

$(\nabla f)(p) = ( \frac{x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2 - ... - x_n^2}{x_1},...,\frac{x_n^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - ... - x_{n-1}^2}{x_n} )(p)$

Comment: Define $f(x)=x_1^2+...+x_n^2 - x_1 \cdot...\cdot x_n$ and then find $\nabla f$, and finally show that it doesn't vanish

Comment: $\nabla f(x)=(2x_1- x_2 \cdot...\cdot x_n, 2x_2- x_1x_3 \cdot...\cdot x_n, ..)=0$ only if $x=0\notin M_f$, so $M_f$ is a differentiable manifold

Comment: @Semsem: There are other points where $\nabla f$ vanishes, but they are not on $f=0$. (E.g., with $n=3$, try $x=y=z=2$ and others.)

Comment: @TedShifrin the theorem assumes that gradient does not vanish on $M_f$ only, am I wrong?

Comment: @Semsem: Of course, you're correct, but in your comment above you claimed the gradient vanished only if $x=0$.

Comment: Do you know where can I find more about this theorem?

Comment: @Kuba It's sometimes called the regular level set theorem. You can find it in introductory books on manifolds.